# Using djangular app in django project

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I want to use [djangular](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular) in my django project but I have a problem.
the problem is that when i want to create djangularapp in django project with this commant `python manage.py startangularapp djangularTest` it shows me the below error:

```
C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\andjango>python manage.py startangularapp djangularTes t Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390,  in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441,  in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\djangular-0.3.0b1-py3.4.egg\djangular\mana gement\commands\startangularapp.py", line 20, in handle
    mgmt.call_command('startapp', app_name, target, **options) 

TypeError: call_command() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error traceback once. The first line clearly shows that instead of using `python manage.py startangularapp djangularTest` you used `python manage.py startangularapp djangularTes t`.This means that django reads two `name` values.

Comment: Thanks,but I've tried all the test cases before asking my question in this place, but none of them was the solution. And ofcourse your solution is not working.